# Memory issues when using G1GC

Tags: java, g1gc

I am a beginner Java developer. My application is using Java 8.

I know that in Java 8, [Parallel GC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html) is the default. When no options are given, the memory is 500MB.

However, giving the [G1 GC](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/hotspot-garbage-collection.html) option increases the memory to 3GB.(`-XX:+UseG1GC`). I know the G1 GC is memory intensive by default, but does it make that much of a difference?

If I want to use G1 GC, do I have to give it a memory option?

Comment: I dont understand why would anyone upvote this, where are your numbers coming from, _exactly_ what have you measured, etc?